# How to access css from a shared folder or from a different location than application?

Tags: css, arrays, html

how to access css from a shared folder or from absolute path or from a different location than application.
something like below

```
    <link href="file://sharedlocation/directory/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: are you running it locally?

Comment: yes, at the moment testing it locally, but requirement is to read css files from a shared location

Comment: then it will be working locally

Comment: you will need to map this shared folder as a virtual folder in your webserver and then link it to your page using this virtual folder

Comment: thanks Luizgrs, and how do we do that please?

Comment: ok , i converted shared folder to virtual , but problem is i need to access multiple files from that location, how can we do that?